# JBoss and a separate TomCat on the same machine

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I need to have on the same machine an installation of JBoss and a separate TomCat running on the same port (80).
Can I realize it and how?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by binding the JBoss and the Tomcat to different IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing two Apache servers, in chrooted environments, listenning to two different IP addresses.

You can then install Tomcat on top of one and JBoss on top of the other.

Comment: Can't I use only one Apache to balance the two different JBoss and TomCat? (eg. JBoss on www1 and TomCat on www2)

Comment: Well, the way I did it, it was just much less error-prone that way, but I assume you can, as long as your Apache is listening to two different IP addresses. Either the address or port, something has to be different if you want to tell one from the other.

Comment: So I intend from what you say that I can realize it if I configure JBoss on one port and TomCan on another one (obviously) different?

Comment: I have not tested that myself, but I don't see why not, as long as you make sure the correct data is sent to each container. Only did that by using two different IPs so far thus, which is much less a headache I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the ports for every one of them to be different and they will work fine.
So in that way you can make them work together.
such as like that:

Tomcat: 127.0.0.1:8080

Wildfly: 127.0.0.1:8081

something like that and they will work perfectly